# Как установить весь grid по центру

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, css-grid, grid

Вопрос не в том, как выровнять элементы грида по центру, а как всю сетку установить по центру.

Т.е. есть wrapper с дивами внутри, wrapper реализован как grid и, например его ширина 1200px. Соответственно весь wrapper с элементами прижимается к левому краю.

Я понимаю, что можно выровнять wrapper через margin: 0 auto. Есть ли какие-то другие способы, более правильные или уместные...

Спасибо.

Comment: а что не так с margin: 0 auto?

Comment: Я не знаю, может это уже неактуальный метод и grid дает какой-то новый функционал...

Comment: ты просто берешь каждый блок и центрируешь его относительно родителя, не совсем понятен вопрос

Comment: @ЭминПогосбеков, grid даёт функционал относительно дочерних элементов. Сам себя блок с display: grid может выровнять только с margin: 0 auto. Если есть задача выровнять именно через grid, тогда этот wrapper надо обернуть ещё в какой-то блок, задать этому новому блоку display: grid; justify-content: center. Но зачем?! )))

Comment: Понятно, просто получается пытаюсь изобрести велосипед там, где он не нужен)

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте добавить к wrapper float:none;

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос